Azure Functions Python PIP issue
I have an azure functions app running on python@3.11
I need to use requests module, so at the top of the .py file I've added 'import requests'. I've also added requests to requirements.txt.
I have CI/CD configured with GitHub Actions. The yml is attached.
My understanding is MS should install the reqs in requirements.txt and make them available however, when I add import requests to the py file. No functions show in the azure portal. If I remoe the import then the functions are again visible.
Is it possible that the packages are being loaded but when the python function app starts it's starting from a different bin and as a result no packages are present? Or am I missing a step/approach with my yaml?
How should I correctly load the requirements.txt? is my flow correct?
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - scubashackchat

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    # environment:
    #   name: 'Production'
    #   url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: red
          tenant-id: red
          subscription-id: red

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'scubashackchat'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          


Refer this. This is how you can install your requirements

perfect thank you. There was no need to create the venv, needed to install to the specific location for azure visibility and my zip command needed adjusting to include hidden folders. If you would like to make an answer I would happily accept

You can refer this example. In short, You don't need to create virtual environment & install packages.  You can use --target option of pip install to install the packages on a specific location(.python_packages/lib/site-packages) for the function visibility.
- name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Pip'
  shell: bash
  run: |
    pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"
    popd

It's also worth noting that you will need to change your zip script to ensure that it includes hidden directories.
- name: Zip artifact for deployment
  run: zip -r release.zip . -x "venv/*" ".git/*" ".github/*" ".gitignore"

